# Как сделать полные права на директории в linux для пользователей, кроме некоторых?

Tags: linux, доступ, chmod, права-доступа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. Есть директория с 40 папками. Необходимо что бы все сотрудники компании видели и могли совершать любые действия с ними и их содержимым. Но так же есть ещё и отдельная категория сотрудников из 5 человек, которая работает с 5 папками из этих 40 штук. У каждого такого человека должен быть полный доступ к одной из этих пяти папок. Но остальные папки они не могли видеть или хотя бы не могли в них зайти. Как такое осуществить?

Comment: организовывайте пользователей в группы.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Users_and_groups

Comment: это лабораторка?

Comment: Нет, на работе задачу поставили. А эти папки я создал для эксперимента. Вопрос уже решил.